# I want to pause Railroad Tycoon 2 with a different key than "Pause". Is that somehow possible?

Tags: railroad-tycoon-2

Most of the question is already in the title, so I provide some explanation why I want something like this.

I pause a lot in the game to micromanage my trains. 

I'd like to play the game on my laptop.

My laptop does not have a Pause key.

Is there maybe a file where I can edit it? Any option welcome.

Comment: You can almost certainly do this with AutoHotKey if it's not possible in-game.  I've got this game but I'm not in front of it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution using AutoHotKey.  Install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  Then create a new text file with the following:

```
 `::SendInput, {Pause}
```

Put this in a file, call it "pause.ahk" (if using Notepad, include the quotes or it will save it as pause.ahk.txt) or similar.  Double click the file to load it.  Now while in Railroad Tycoon, you can use the accent/tilde key instead of pause.

If you want to bind it to another key, just put another key before the :: in the script above.  Almost any key works, for some of the more complex ones (ie, F-keys or the number pad) refer to [this page.](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

When you want your key back, just quit the script by right-clicking on the green "H" icon in your system tray, then choose Exit.

It's also possible to make it only activate when Railroad Tycoon 2 is the active window, by adding this line to the top:

```
 #IfWinActive ahk_class RT2_TSC
```

... assuming you've got the same version of RT2 that I do.

Comment: I'll check it out asap. Sounds like it would work. Thanks a lot. Answer will be marked as soon as verified. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work with Steam when streaming the game from the Desktop PC to my Laptop. Now trying to install locally and retry.

Answer (score 1):

The plus and minus keys change the game speed. Set it to zero to pause (you can also you the little yellow slider on the right of the UI to change game speed). This is how I've always done it (RRT2 Plat), it works in all the menus, etc. I can't guarantee it works in earlier (non-Plat) versions.